# How to read the identifier 'class' in Flex?

Tags: c++, regex, compiler-construction, flex-lexer, lexical-analysis

I am trying to write a compiler for COOL language and am right now at lexical analysis. Concretely, Flex matches the largest pattern as I understand.

Thus if you have in Flex:

```
class A inherits B
```

Now if my token for `class` is returned by following pattern:

```
^"class"   return CLASS;
```

For my `inherits` token:

```
^"class"[ ]+[a-zA-Z]+[0-9]?[ ]+"inherits"[ ]+ return INHERITS;
```

Now since flex matches the largest pattern, it will always return `INHERITS` and never class. Is there a work around to this problem?

I can here return token for `class` alone. But how do I return token for `inherits` since it MUST be preceded by a `class` token and its name followed by another string token?

But if I try to impose constraints on `inherits`, then flex will match the largest pattern not class alone.

Then should I return the enums/number for class identifier individually? And if I do that, how do I identify 'inherits' identifier?

EDIT:

```
class A inherits B {
   main(): SELF_TYPE{...}
}
```

How does the flex match against `main`? My reflexer differentiates between TypeID which is `A` and `main`, which it declares `ObjectID`. The only it can do that is by looking ahead at the paranthesis and if it finds `(`, it declares an ObjectID. But if I do that, I counter the same problem as above: flex will never match against `(` but always `main(`.

Comment: Why are you trying to parse multiple tokens at a time with Flex regular expressions? Scan a token at a time, leave the parsing to your parser.

Comment: Why do you want to insist that `class` appear at the beginning of a line? I don't believe that's the intent of the COOL lexical structure.

Comment: @mrjoltcola That is what I wanted to do. But what if I put an `inherits` some where in the program randomly. Essentially an error. Should I even then return the token? Or generate an error?

Comment: @user1343318 - Yes, you should return the token; let a parser handle whether the token INHERITS is legal in which context. Your lexer should not worry about context and it cannot possibly hope to account for every possibility. See my answer. What are you writing your parser with? If the answer is "Flex" then that is your problem. Either write a recursive descent parser that calls yylex(), or create a Yacc/Bison grammar to combine with Flex. They were designed to work together. A good start is to get the "Lex and Yacc" book.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to do too much in Flex, and perhaps you misunderstand the role and boundaries of the lexical phase. You shouldn't be attempting to parse the whole sentence with a Flex regex alone. Flex's job is to consume a stream of text, and convert it to a stream of integer tokens. The sentence you've provided:

```
 class A inherits B
```

represents multiple tokens from a language that requires parsing. Flex is not a parser, it is a lexical scanner/tokenizer. (Technically it is a parser of bytes or characters, but you want to "parse" atomic units that represent the words of your language, not characters).

So there are 4 distinct tokens (atomic units), also known as ***TERMINALS*** in the above sentence:  [CLASS, A, INHERITS, B].
You need an IDENTIFIER rule for Flex, such that anything that doesn't match a token, falls through to an IDENTIFIER, so the tokens returned by Flex to the parser are:

```
 CLASS IDENTIFIER INHERITS IDENTIFIER
```

The job for Flex is to parse each word / token and convert the text to distinct integer values to be consumed by Bison or any other parser.

You typically have a Yacc/Bison BNF grammar to handle:

```
 class_decl:
         CLASS IDENTIFIER
       | CLASS IDENTIFIER INHERITS IDENTIFIER
 ;
```

So your Lex rule would be thus, and you need to return the IDENTIFIER token to parser, while attaching the actual symbol (A, B). You get that from the yytext variable:

```
LETTER            [a-zA-Z_]
DIGIT             [0-9]
LETTERDIGIT       [a-zA-Z0-9_]
%%

"class"         return(CLASS);
"inherits"      return(INHERITS);

{LETTER}{LETTERDIGIT}* {
           yylval.sym = new Symbol(yytext); 
           yylval.sym->line = line;
           fprintf(stderr, "TOKEN IDENTIFIER(%s)\n", yytext);
           return(IDENTIFIER);
        }
```

If you are really trying to do all of this within Flex, then it is possible, but you will end up with a mess, like if you try to parse HTML with regex... :)

Comment: Thank you @mrjoltcola. Can you please see if you can answer the edited question above?

Comment: @user1343318 - My answer already addresses your edit. IDENTIFIER handles "main". Frankly, you are demonstrating why you shouldn't parse with lex / regular expressions. Keep your lexer as context-free as possible. You haven't addressed my assertion that you are trying to avoid writing a parser, whether with a generator like yacc or bison, or by hand? In any compiler I've ever written, handle "main" as an IDENTIFIER and store it in a symbol table (just a hash table will suffice for you). Then the parse stage can figure out what "main" is.

Comment: Compiling = Tokenizing (flex) + Syntax (parser) + Context / Semantic processing (AST or interpreter that you write by hand). Are you doing this for a class? Has the professor covered the parsing stage and Yacc/Bison tools yet?

Comment: I am doing this for Stanford's MOOC Compiler's class. So the Professor is only focusing upon the lexical analysis stage in the first assignment. I am doing it myself, alone so facing problems, challenges. Another question: Should I differ between `main` and `maining`? Should I start a state machine whenever I encounter `m` and then check if it is `main` the keyword or `maining` which is a variable?

Comment: Yes, you should differ between main and maining. Flex uses greedy matching, so it will prefer the longest match, in this case, the IDENTIFIER rule will match "maining" over "main" because it will keep consuming input until an accept or exit state. You should write your flex rules such that whitespace is also matched (and ignored), so whitespace ends up being a delimiter (or empty token that is never returned to parser), and as a result, main would never be matched within "maining" even if there were a specific token rule for it, because the accept state for main would expect whitespace or EOF.

Comment: If your class is covering the lexical analysis stage, then limit your thinking to lexical analysis and just tokenize the stream. Forget trying to differentiate between "main" the keyword and "maining" the variable until you start the parsing stage (later in your class).

Comment: will you be kind enough to explain how flex is using these two lines? `yylval.sym = new Symbol(yytext);` and `yylval.sym->line = line;`. Concretely, I understand that flex is inserting these values into a symbol table. But how does flex keeps a record of `yylval.sym` since this value will be different for each of the emerging tokens?

Comment: yylval is the token that is passed to the parser. So for Identifier / Symbol tokens, I create a Symbol type (C++ actually) with the original text and attach it to the token so the parser can use it. It is the parser that stores the Symbol into a symbol table. You could just as easily use a plain string / char *. sym->line is to track the original line number where the token was scanned, useful for error messages.

Comment: The whole point of the lexer is to break the input text up into individual integer tokens that can be efficiently used in a parser engine. The lexer can attach as many attributes (contextual information) to the token as possible before passing to the parser.

Comment: thank you for the enormous help. Just to make myself absoulutely sure: the parser receives two inputs from Lexical Analyser, namely, the `yylval.sym` and identifier which can be `INT`, `STRING`, or something else. Concretely, as soon as it encounters text, it separates it into a token, and returns that value to Parser.